# GNU parallel - running command through multiple ssh jumphosts

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, gnu

I need to run commands on multiple hosts accessible via multiple jumphosts.

I have a slf file

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -nJ jumphost1,user@jumphost2 user@worker1
ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -nJ jumphost1,user@jumphost2 user@worker2
ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -nJ jumphost1,user@jumphost2 user@worker3
...
```

Running parallel I get

```
$ parallel --slf workers-ssh "ls -la"
parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. You either know what you
parallel: Warning: are doing (in which case: YOU ARE AWESOME!) or you forgot
parallel: Warning: ::: or :::: or to pipe data into parallel. If so
parallel: Warning: consider going through the tutorial: man parallel_tutorial
parallel: Warning: Press CTRL-D to exit.
parallel: Warning: Could not figure out number of cpus on worker1 (). Using 1.
```

Jumphost and worker IPs are dynamically generated in previous scripts so I would prefer no `~/.ssh/config` edits.

What is the correct way to solve this problem with gnu parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no big problem in your slf file but in the way you specify the command.

When you run `parallel`, you should specify the "variable" part, or `parallel` will ask you to enter that part in stdin just like your situation.

In your case, you have to fill the command in this way:

```
parallel --slf workers-ssh ::: "ls -la"
```

which is equivalent to

```
parallel --slf workers-ssh {} ::: "ls -la"
```

So far you should be able to issue commands on remote machines, but since only one argumant (`"ls -la"`) is given, only one machine will be connected. If you want to issue `ls -la` on all machines, you may apply the following edit:

`commands.txt`

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -nJ jumphost1,user@jumphost2 user@worker1 "ls -la"
ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -nJ jumphost1,user@jumphost2 user@worker2 "ls -la"
ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -nJ jumphost1,user@jumphost2 user@worker3 "ls -la"
```

then run

```
parallel :::: commands.txt
```

---

Or another way

```
parallel ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -nJ jumphost1,user@jumphost2 user@worker{} ls -a ::: {1..3}
```

Substitute by real IPs.

```
parallel ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -nJ jumphost1,user@jumphost2 user@{} ls -a ::: ip1 ip2 ip3
```

Comment: First two commands don't work for me. However the last command is the simple one-liner what I was looking for. Instead of `::: {1..3}` I'm using `:::: worker-ips`. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it's helpful. `{1..3}` is a substitution that will be put in `worker{}` as `worker1` `worker2` `worker3`. I'll make a more clear edit.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use `--ssh`:

```
parallel --ssh 'ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -nJ jumphost1,user@jumphost2' -S user@worker1 ::: "ls -la"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two available options in GNU parallel designed for this use-case.

without arguments:

```
parallel --slf sshloginfile.txt --nonall "hostname"
```

and with arguments:

```
parallel --slf sshloginfile.txt --onall ::: hostname
```